# How to reverse words in a string in HIVE?

Tags: hive, hql, hiveql

Is it possible to reverse the order of words in a string, which are separated by a single space, in Hive SQL?

I saw there are function like `reverse` but it only work for string (ofc, we can use it to reverse words by doing 1) reverse whole string 2) reverse each word, it's easy to written in java or other language, but I am not sure how to do it in SQL).

Any ideas?

For example,

```
// assuming I have one column field in a table like 
WITH example_data AS (
  SELECT "I am learning Hive SQL" as my_string
)

I want to return "SQL Hive learning am I".
```

Comment: I see creating custom UDF is best option here. https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HivePlugins

Comment: Thanks, Raid. Yeah, that seems still kind of complex, lol. But agree that it might be the best option. Also surprised with the current built-in functions, we can not achieve that..